# DataJpaTest not working with mysql full text search

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to test this method:

```
@Query(value = "select *  from table "
+ "where match(name_column) AGAINST(:name in BOOLEAN MODE)", nativeQuery = true)

List<ManagedGroup> findByGroupNameMatches(@Param("name") String groupName);
```

The test itself :

```
@Test
  public void findByGroupNameMatches_should_return_when_contains_part_of_name(){
    ManagedGroup managedGroup = prepearGroup(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    managedGroup.setGroupName("def123");
    testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(managedGroup);

    // in desperate tries - tried to save it via repositroty as well
    groupRepository.save(managedGroup);

    //the groups can be found - there is two groups with names 'def123' and 'default name'
    List<ManagedGroup> res =  groupRepository.findAll();
    Pageable pageable = new OffsetLimitPageRequest(0, 10,  Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));

    List<ManagedGroup> managedGroupPage = groupRepository.findByGroupNameMatches("+def*");
     //managedGroupPage is empty after the method is called
    Assertions.assertEquals(defaultManagedGroup, managedGroupPage.get(0));
  }
```

The test fails cause I get empty result from findByGroupNameMatches. I've tried saving and retriviengthe entity via jdbcTemplate - still no result. Other tests work as well, so I guess that it is not the problem.

The method works in implemented controller and is already tested by QA team.

I've also tried to run the test against QA db and it works with the entities, persisted before tests are booted. I am sure that the problem is with persisting it, but I still cannot find the solution. I've tried different combinations of flush and etc.. and still no result

Providing more info to reproduce the test:

```
static final MySQLContainer DATABASE = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.23");

  static {
    DATABASE.start();
  }

  static class Initializer implements
      ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
      TestPropertyValues.of(
          "spring.datasource.url=" + DATABASE.getJdbcUrl(),
          "spring.datasource.username=" + DATABASE.getUsername(),
          "spring.datasource.password=" + DATABASE.getPassword()
      ).applyTo(context.getEnvironment());
    }
```

The test class is annotated with

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable(named = "RUN_INTEGRATION_TEST", matches = "false")
@DirtiesContext
  }
```

Comment: What kind of table are you using? MyInnoDB or ISAM? Does it work when you use longer and or simpler search terms like `-default`?

Comment: I am using the InnoDB. It does not work at all, tried all kinds of text 
Also tried to run script manually - all good

Comment: How do you create the schema in the test? Is it automatically generated from hibernate?

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL after the Prepare, etc, is finished.  Or provide an example `SELECT` that 'fails' via mysql commandline tool or Workbench or phpmyadmin.

Comment: As I am using the native query—the generated select is just identical to one that is provided in the method declaration. It work in Workbench and live application environment, but fails when I am running Test on the entity, that was persisted through testEntityManager

Comment: Add `@Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)` to the test class and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @h.a. (propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED) is creating the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found. Without it I still get same result.

Comment: Hello Yolomiys , referring to your last comment it is quit obvious that there is not EntityManager found , as far as i think at each transaction an entityManager should be instanciated for that could you please add @PersistenceContext  an then retry with the last modifications

Answer (score 1):

Hello shouldnt you have a table name for this native query

```
@Query(value = "select *  from table TABLE_NAME "
+ "where match(name_column) AGAINST(:name in BOOLEAN MODE)", nativeQuery = true)

List<ManagedGroup> findByGroupNameMatches(@Param("name") String groupName);
```

Also you should flush when Transactional annotation not there

```
// in desperate tries - tried to save it via repositroty as well
    groupRepository.save(managedGroup);
```

use groupRepository.flush or saveAndFlush